# Firebase getAuth().currentUser returns null

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to get my current user from getAuth() but it returns null.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'

const Profile = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null)

  const auth = getAuth()

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(auth.currentUser)
  }, [])

  return <h1>Profile</h1>
}

export default Profile
```

Comment: That's bcs you're not authenticated at all.

Comment: have you add a user yet ? this won't work with out authentication